# mysql calculate and sort next 10 birthday's

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate and sort the upcoming birthday's from my users.
there are many query's here where you can achieve this but my data is stored different than the most databases.

My database is as followed :

```
p_id | pfield_id | user_id | Profile_value
```

the date is stored in the `profile_value where pfield_id = '1'`

what is the best way to achieve this?

I want to have the `user_id` and upcoming birthday

Much Thanks

[Sample Data]

```
Where "some data" is not a date.
------------------------------------------------
| p_id  |   pfield_id  |  user_id  | Profile_value |
|   1   |      1       |    1      |  20-12-2000   |
|   2   |      2       |    1      |  some data    |
|   3   |      1       |    2      |  15-07-2000   |
|   4   |      3       |    2      |  some data    |
|   5   |      4       |    2      |  some data    |
|   6   |      1       |    3      |  25-10-2000   |
|   7   |      2       |    2      |  some data    |
```

Comment: Provide some sample data or create a fiddle.

Comment: i have added some data, if you need any other data let me know

Comment: This `some data` contain a `date` or what?

Comment: `'some data` contains not a `date` it contains other user data like zipcode and stuff

Answer (score 0):

User `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT user_id,Profile_value        //Columns
FROM tableName                      //Table
WHERE 
    pfield_id='1' AND               //pfield_id equals to 1
    Profile_value >= CURDATE();     //Date in table >= current date (today's date)
ORDER BY DATE(Profile_value) ASC    //Order from most recent`
```

**EDIT**: *added `DATE` function so it can get ordered.*

Comment: Except the dates are not in a sortable format where `2000-10-25` would be.

Comment: maybe now, with `DATE()` function

Comment: i have changed the date's so query wil work but how can i get the upcomming 10 birthday's from this, including the age?

Comment: @spotje I have changed the sql query! Is the `age` in the same table ?